# blender exporting 3d model that works with min3d

Tags: android, 3d, blender, min3d

I am new to 3d model on android. after reading many topics i decided to use blender as graphical application and min3d as android 3d library.
So i have a few questions :

1. what is the options that i have selected when exporting the object to be compatible working on mini3d.
2. how i can motion the object from code (not pre defined motion in graphical application) (3d human model i want to write using min3d like this to move hands up : or something like this).

I will appreciate if there is any other suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just share some experience and sorry for the bad english.

For the first question, I recommend you to export as .3ds or .obj file when using min3d as your library. Also, just an experience on using this lib, try not to import an object that contains more than 20000 triangle in min3d. In other words, you may import many objects with each obects having less than 20000 triangle. As the object will have a higher chance to be crashed or even some memory overflow situation.

For the second question, the min3d is based on openglES. This is a very simple 3d object display library. If you want to make some animation like moving arm, you need to move every point of arm to a new postion inorder to make it like moving. That means you need to know and calculate every potints of the arm.

In this case, I will suggest you to try other 3d implementation like unity3d which is easier to implement complicated animation of 3d objects. However, if the animation/movement you want is not really complicated, may be you can try export the 3dhuman body in several parts and "combine" them on the scene by min3d. After that, you may move a several part easier.